# How to insert multiple rows in a mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

hey guys i would like to ask how to insert multiple row in mysql database, despite the fact that i already know how to insert one row in mysql database but i dont know how to insert multiple row.

here is the example of my layout
[image]

and here is the exact scenario

when i fill up the dates and remarks then i click the add button it should be inserted in my database.

this is my php script I know there is something wrong with it.

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");
if(!empty($_POST)){

        if(empty($_POST['date']) || empty($_POST['remark'])){
            $response["Success"] = 0;
            $response["Message"] = "Please complete all fields.";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }

        $query = "SELECT 1 FROM tb_attendance WHERE date = :date";
        $query_params = array(
                                ':date'=> $_POST['date'],
                                );

        try{
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            $response["Success"] = 0;
            $response["Message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again...";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
            if($row){
                $response["Success"] = 0;
                $response["Message"] = "I'm sorry, this Record is already existed.";
                die(json_encode($response));
            }

            $query = "INSERT INTO tb_attendance (date, remark) VALUES(:date, :remark)";
            $query_params = array(
                                    ':date' => $_POST['date'],
                                    ':remark' => $_POST['remark']

                                  );

        try{
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex){
                $response["Success"] = 0;
                $response["Message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again...";
                die(json_encode($response));
            }
                $response["Success"] = 1;
                $response["Message"] = "Attendance Successfully Recorded.";
                echo json_encode($response);

}else{
?>

    <form action="addAttendance.php" method="post">
    Date: <input type="text" name="date"><br>
    Remark: <input type="text" name="remark"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: Well dear friend, what have you tried so far?

Comment: well there's nothing sir but i review all related questions and i know its not what im looking for :(

Comment: Well in order to get some help, you are going to have to show some effort..

Comment: okay sir i'll get back to you later when i tried something and still didn't solve my problem.

Comment: for inserting multiple rows we use loops. If u have tried and got success on inserting a single data/row to database then research on how to insert multiple data.. Send your data in json form and use php for multiple insert

Comment: i updated my question and i added my php script and i think there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply send post data in array then play with that array to create a query for inserting bunch of records

Answer (score 0):

Try following structure for multiple inserts

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`key1`, `key2`, `key3`, `key4`) VALUES
('val11', 'val12', 'val13', ''),
('val21', 'val22', 'val23', ''),
('val31', 'val32', 'val33', ''),
('val41', 'val42', 'val43', '');
```

Comment: uhh it is not only 3 rows but it can be 20 or 30 or 50 something like that

Comment: But that you can do with some script in php

Comment: i updated my question and i added my php script and i think there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider you have an array of multiple values like

```
$array = array (
      0 => array(
          0=>"val11",
          1=>"val12",
          2=>"val13",
          3=>"val14"
      ),
      1 => array(
          0=>"val11",
          1=>"val12",
          2=>"val13",
          3=>"val14"
      ),
      2 => array(
          0=>"val11",
          1=>"val12",
          2=>"val13",
          3=>"val14"
      ),
      3 => array(
          0=>"val11",
          1=>"val12",
          2=>"val13",
          3=>"val14"
      )
)
```

You can then implode each index of array like

```
foreach($array as &$value){
    $value = "('".implode("', '",$value)."')"
}
```

this will return an array like

```
$array = array (
      0 => "('val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14')",
      1 => "('val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14')",
      2 => "('val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14')",
      3 => "('val11', 'val12', 'val13', 'val14')"
)
```

then You can implode this array with comma

```
$array = implode (", "$array);
```

This will return you a string like

```
('val11', 'val12', 'val13', ''), ('val21', 'val22', 'val23', ''), ('val31', 'val32', 'val33', ''), ('val41', 'val42', 'val43', '');
```

And you can append this string with

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`key1`, `key2`, `key3`, `key4`) VALUES
```

So you would get the complete query as

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`key1`, `key2`, `key3`, `key4`) VALUES ('val11', 'val12', 'val13', ''), ('val21', 'val22', 'val23', ''), ('val31', 'val32', 'val33', ''), ('val41', 'val42', 'val43', '');
```

And as you can guess in array you can have as many records you want it could be either 1 or 100.

Comment: i updated my question and i added my php script and i think there is something wrong with it.